# Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, parsing, json

I am having parsing errors.
this is my responserequest which I send to the server:

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="http://g.comli.com/register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String rollnumber, String name, String branch, String email, String phone, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("rollnumber",rollnumber);
        params.put("name",name);
        params.put("email",email);
        params.put("branch",branch);
        params.put("phone",phone);
    }
 @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
```

My login activity code:

```
Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success){
                            Intent intentC = new Intent(UserAreaStudent.this, Confirmation.class);
                            intentC.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            UserAreaStudent.this.startActivity(intentC);
                            UserAreaStudent.this.finish();

                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAreaStudent.this);
                            builder.setMessage("register failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("retry",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            RegisterRequest registerRequest= new RegisterRequest(rollnumber, name,branch,email,phone,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(UserAreaStudent.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

        }
    });
```

My php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");

$rollnumber=$_POST["rollnumber"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$branch=$_POST["branch"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phonenumber = $_POST["phone"];



$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO register (rollnumber, name, branch, email,phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"sssss",$rollnumber,$name, $username,$email, $password,$phone,$branch);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

catlogs:
[image]

please help!!..

Comment: Specify text received from request

Comment: You mean to say the text received from the server?

Comment: Yes. You send some parameters to server, so give the responce.